# Array filter based on multiple columns

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Suppose I have a `4 x n` array:

```
A =    [1 2 3 4; ...
        2 4 8 9; ...
        6 7 9 4; ...
        1 8 3 4];
```

I want to filter the whole array based on the content of the first two columns.

For example, if I want to return array rows which contain a 2 in the first two columns, the answer I'm looking for isL

```
R = [1 2 3 4;...
     2 4 8 9];
```

Or, if I want to return rows containing a 1 in the first two columns, the answer I'm looking for is...

```
A = [1 2 3 4;...
     1 8 3 4];
```

I'm sure it's obvious but how can I do this in MATLAB?  Filtering the whole array based on `find` or evaluation commands (e.g. `A == 2`) is totally fine. It's the filtering based on multiple columns in any order I can't figure out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check for **a given number**, just apply [`any`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/any.html) along 2nd dimension restricted to the desired columns, and use that as a [logical index](http://matlabtricks.com/post-23/tutorial-on-matrix-indexing-in-matlab) to select the desired rows:

```
cols = [1 2]; %// columns to look at
val = 1; %// value to look for
R = A(any(A(:, cols)==val, 2), :);
```

---

If you want to look for **several values**, for example, select all rows that contain either 2 or 3 in columns 1 or 2: use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) instead of `==`:

```
cols = [1 2]; %// columns to look at
vals = [2 3]; %// values to look for
R = A(any(ismember(A(:, cols), vals), 2), :);
```

---

If you want to check if the numbers are **within a range**:

```
cols = [1 2]; %// columns to look at
v1 = 6; %// numbers should be greater or equal to this...
v2 = 8; %// ...and less than this
R = A(any(A(:, cols)>=v1, 2) & any(A(:, cols)<v2, 2), :);
```

Comment: +1 - I was actually about to type out an answer and you beat me lol.  Not surprised.  Nice job Luis.

Comment: @rayryeng This one was easy :-) It was just a matter of being quick/lucky

Comment: Great answer! What if it was a search in the first two columns for values greater / equal to 2 AND less than 8 ie a range as opposed to a specific value

Comment: Are your numbers always integers? If so, use my second approach with `vals = 2:7`. If not, let me know and I'll update my answer

Comment: They can be non-integers too

Comment: Then you only need a minor modification of the first approach to now include _two_ conditions. It should be pretty easy to figure out for yourself, but anyway I've updated my answer with this